# How to Store Log Data in Json format in android?

Tags: java, android, json, logging

I am logging events in the android application.

Now I need to store the `Log` data that is generated by the application in **JSON** format.How can I do this... any suggestion for this?

this is the code for logging various events of the Android application using `AppEventLogger` class

```
public  class AppEventLogger {

private static final String TAG = AppEventsLogger.class.getCanonicalName();


public void Loginlog(Long id,  boolean result, int failedattempts, int attempts,long eventTime, long mLastInteractionTime) {
    final long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    logLogin(
        id,
        result,
        failedattempts,
        attempts,
        eventTime,
        mLastInteractionTime);

}


public void Logoutlog(long eventTime ,boolean isLoggedOut,){
    final long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    logLogout(
        eventTime,
        isLoggedOut);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

**Changes in your class:**

```
package com.nct.dhruv.demotest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by user31 on 4/12/17.
 */

public class AppEventLogger {

    private Context mContext;
    private String appContextName = "AppEventLogger";

    public AppEventLogger(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        Loginlog(1, true, 11, 112, 121, 12);
        Logoutlog(2, false);

    }

    //private static final String TAG = AppEventsLogger.class.getCanonicalName();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    public void Loginlog(long id, boolean result, int failedattempts, int attempts, long eventTime, long mLastInteractionTime) {
        eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        createJson(appContextName , " ID : " + id + " Result : " + result + " failedattempts : " + failedattempts + " attempts : " + attempts + " eventTime : " + " mLastInteractionTime : " + mLastInteractionTime);

                    /*logLogin(id,
                    result,
                    failedattempts,
                    attempts,
                    eventTime,
                    mLastInteractionTime);*/


    }


    public void Logoutlog(long eventTime, boolean isLoggedOut) {
        eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        createJson(appContextName, " eventTime : " + eventTime + " isLoggedOut : " + isLoggedOut);

    }


    private void createJson(String context, String logData) {
        try {
            Log.d("data", logData);


            JSONObject jsonObjOne = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjOne.put("context", context);
            jsonObjOne.put("logData", logData);


            jsonArray.put(jsonObjOne);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("JsonData", jsonArray);

           // Log.e("Your_JSON", json.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Out Put:**

```
{
    "JsonData": [{
        "context": "AppEventLogger",
        "logData": " ID : 1 Result : true failedattempts : 11 attempts : 112 eventTime :  mLastInteractionTime : 12"
    }, {
        "context": "AppEventLogger",
        "logData": " eventTime : 1512374548115 isLoggedOut : false"
    }]
}
```

---

**Old answer**

Your LOG string goes here:

```
 private void createJson(String logData) {
        try {
            Log.d("data", logData);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            jsonObj.put("log", logData);

            jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
            Log.e("Your_JSON",jsonObj.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

call this method from where you want to store  LOG data

```
createJson("12343434");
```

**Output:**

```
{"log":"12343434"}
```

---

New code to convert `String` to `JSON`

**StringToJson.java file**

```
/**
 * Created by dhruv on 18/12/17.
 */

public class StringToJson {

    private Context context;

    //Crating constructor
    public StringToJson(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getJson(String name, String sport, String age, String id, ArrayList lastScores) {

        String result = "";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();


        try {


            mainJson.put("name", name);
            mainJson.put("sport", sport);
            mainJson.put("age", age);
            mainJson.put("id", id);

            if (!lastScores.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < lastScores.size(); i++) {
                    jsonArr.put(lastScores.get(i));
                }

            }

            mainJson.put("lastScores", jsonArr);

            json.put("result", mainJson);

            result = json.get("result").toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java (simple class that call method)**

```
public class StringToJs extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StringToJson stringToJson;
    private ArrayList jsonArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_string_to_js);

        jsonArray = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            jsonArray.add(i);
        }

        stringToJson = new StringToJson(StringToJs.this);

        Log.e("JSON: ", stringToJson.getJson("my_name", "Cricket", "23", "1", jsonArray));


    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    "name": "my_name",
    "sport": "Cricket",
    "age": "23",
    "id": "1",
    "lastScores": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

Comment: i have created a class called AppEventLogger which logs  the data in the android application .It contains various methods like LoginLog(long id,long eventTime,.....),LogoutLog(...) etc so now how i need to store data that is obtained from these methods in json format

Comment: ok than create a global array and store data in that array and pass it to jsonArray

Comment: tell me one thing why you want to  store Log Data and concert to JSON ?

Comment: i am using this log data for analytics purpose

Comment: Yup this is good , but u also do analytics by showing LOG in LogCat

Comment: and if you want to still want to create JSON of LOG than please share you class file

Comment: we want to log data in file because we want to use this dataset in the weka analytics tool

Comment: @priya are you want to store all data ?

Comment: what is the need of this statement  ?                                                Loginlog(1, true, 11, 112, 121, 12);
        Logoutlog(2, false);

Comment: @priya ahahah i just passing a value in for method calling

Comment: `you will be get :{
 "JsonData": [{
  "context": "AppEventLogger",
  "logData": " ID : 1 Result : true failedattempts : 11 attempts : 112 eventTime :  mLastInteractionTime : 12"
 }, {
  "context": "AppEventLogger",
  "logData": " eventTime : 1512374548115 isLoggedOut : false"
 }]
}` this out put by using Loginlog(1, true, 11, 112, 121, 12)

Comment: we can remove those two statements in my program kn/

Comment: yup you will remove those line, and you will pass your own parameter

Comment: @priya means that you will pass your response parameter like Loginlog(id,...,...,)

Comment: @priya welcome i think you  will get my point , b d way you can right vote to me LOL

Comment: Hii i have done with logging part. Can I know how to write the logs to the file

Comment: @priya from where you want to store file ?

Comment: from queue to file

Comment: in the tablet which i am using

Comment: In this case my suggestion is , store your logCat Data in to MySql Database means parsing data to php side

Comment: @priya can you approve the question asked by you that edited by me

Comment: I have a doubt how i need to initiate the AppeventLogger class call from another class

Comment: @priya  can't understand what you are trying to tell

Comment: Means you want to call AppeventLogger class in  Other class?

Comment: i have written appeventlogger which contain  loginlog,logoutlog etc ,i have also created a file to log these events.whether i need to appeventlogger from anyother class so that it starts logging the data related to login ,logout.

Comment: jsonString = {
  "name" : "Ronaldo",
  "sport" : "soccer",
  "age" : 25,
  "id" : 121,
  "lastScores" : [ 2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
}
I need to generate data in the given format.So how i need to write interface to generate this format of data

Comment: `jsonString = { "name" : "Ronaldo", "sport" : "soccer", "age" : 25, "id" : 121, "lastScores" : [ 2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1 ] }`

you want to create this type of  `JSON` ?

Comment: yes I want to create the interface in this format so that i can implement in my other classes like loginLog etc..

Comment: i can able to understand what do you going to do.. as u told what i understood that u want to create a JSON of this format  

am i right? or wrong ?

Comment: Previously i had done AppEventLogger which contain methods like LoginLog,LogoutLog etc. But now i want to create ILog a Interface to convert string to Json(). then create a class called as LoginLog implement this ILog ..

Comment: but why `interface` you cant also create a class  that does same thing via its method,..........  in class u can pass Data that u want to convert String ton JSON

Comment: if i create the interface i can just implement it the classes which i need kn soo

Comment: In a class how i need to write method to convert string to Json

Comment: hii @priya see my updated answer i have added new code for you

Comment: its `StringToJson` not  `stringToJson`

Comment: @priya first u need create   `StringToJson`

Comment: @priya check my updated answer  and remove your previous added class  and let me know

Comment: thank you.  If i want to do same thing using interface how i need to do please help me in this......

Comment: please tell me how to create a interface to convert string to Json()??They want interface only to convert String to Json().

Comment: please tell me how to create a interface to convert string to Json()? They want interface only to convert string to Json().

Comment: i will told u later bcs  ryt now i have some work to do first

Comment: can we use Map/HashMap to store log data?

Comment: @priya yes you can use `HashMap` Key nad value pair but, in this case u can only store Unique Key HashMap dose not accept duplicate value

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void log(Context context,String data) {
        try {
            Log.i("info",data);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("log.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.append(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        } 
    }
```

Comment: can i create a interface which implements the Json format to store the log data

Comment: @priya yes you can

Comment: how i need to do ?